# Swipe.js - prev/next issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swipe

I have a single page with multiple instances of Swipe.js running. They are loaded dynamically through the CMS so hard coding values isn't really possible.

I have followed the steps outlined in this other post:
[Generate Swipe JS slider for each slider DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305631/generate-swipe-js-slider-for-each-slider-div)

I can get everything working except the last part where they talk about dynamically loading the prev/next controls for each player.

I create multiple sliders with:

```
var swipes = []
$('.slider').each(function(i, obj) {
    swipes[i] = new Swipe(obj);
});
```

Then in the template code that structures each slider I have the following:

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>

<div id="swipes<?php echo $counter; ?>" class='slider swipe gallery'>

    <div class='swipe-wrap'>

        //Images go here

    </div>

    <div>  
        <button onclick='swipes<?php echo $counter; ?>.prev()'>prev</button> 
        <button onclick='swipes<?php echo $counter; ?>.next()'>next</button>
    </div>

<?php $counter++; ?>

</div>
```

The PHP counter does it's job perfectly, but for some reason when I click on a prev/next button I get the follow Console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'next'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention the initial code snippet is being loaded on Document Ready.

Comment: Can you show us a live example, or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Or at least, the generated code?

Comment: I've fixed it by moving the `var swipes=[]` outside of the `document.ready` function and amending the `onclick` snytax.